# search for python libary to build display with images and videos

Tags: python, user-interface, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to write a program for a Raspberry 2B. The Job of the program is to show some images and a video based on a variable.
I can't really find a good library to build my visual output. It should show a Fullscreen window with sections. Each section should display images and videos. These may be changed based on the variable I mentioned. Furthermore, I may need to reposition, scale, crop the images at run time.

So basically, I need a UI, but I don't need necessarily user input options.
I am pretty new to Python, so sorry if I don't see an obvious choice.

Thanks for every advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only library I'm aware that might suit is [Napari](https://napari.org/). This library was really built with image analysis in mind, but I expect the API can do all the things you want.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Or make it a comment rather than an answer, since a link-only post can't be an answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry it took so long.
I had some problems installing Napari. In the end, I'll work with Tkinter and Tkvideo. These have everything I need.
Still, thanks for your recommendation.